# Can I overide CSS values after form submit using JavaScript Function?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a simple form where you can upload html files. I have 3 files:

- Main HTML file - which contains my form and JavaScript function.
- Secondary HTML file - this is used to upload to the form.
- CSS file - this is for the secondary HTML file.

I want to override the CSS value of the uploaded html file using this function in my main HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Changing the style of another HTML File</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
function updateSize() {
  var nBytes = 0,
      oFiles = document.getElementById("uploadInput").files,
      nFiles = oFiles.length;
  for (var nFileId = 0; nFileId < nFiles; nFileId++) {
    nBytes += oFiles[nFileId].size;
  }
  var sOutput = nBytes + " bytes";
  // optional code for multiples approximation
  for (var aMultiples = ["KiB", "MiB", "GiB", "TiB", "PiB", "EiB", "ZiB", "YiB"], nMultiple = 0, nApprox = nBytes / 1024; nApprox > 1; nApprox /= 1024, nMultiple++) {
    sOutput = nApprox.toFixed(3) + " " + aMultiples[nMultiple] + " (" + nBytes + " bytes)";
  }
  // end of optional code
  document.getElementById("fileNum").innerHTML = nFiles;
  document.getElementById("fileSize").innerHTML = sOutput;
}

function extract() {
var el = document.getElementById("test");
el.style.background = 'green';
el.style.color = 'red';
}
</script>

<body onload="updateSize();">
<form>
<p><input id="uploadInput" type="file" name="myFiles" onchange="updateSize();" multiple> selected files: <span id="fileNum">0</span>; total size: <span id="fileSize">0</span></p>
<p><input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="extract()"></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The Secondary HTML file has the following code (This will be submitted to the form):

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css" />
</head> 
<body> 
<div id="test">This is a div</div>
</body> 
</html>
```

This is my CSS file for my Secondary HTML file:

```
#test {
background-color: red;
color: yellow;
};
```

However, it doesn't work. Where I'm I going wrong?

Comment: your are calling this function or not ? if yes when, if not this is your issue

Comment: @TemaniAfif Function is being called when you submit the form after you click on the 'Submit' button on the form.

Comment: but we don't see this in your code :)

Comment: `name="extract()"` Noooooooooo... It should be `onsubmit="extract()"`. Also where is id="test" in your form? Which element you want to change style?

Comment: @TemaniAfif I've edited the question.

Comment: @Sankar The id="test" is on the HTML file that is being uploaded.

Comment: You are saying that you want to change the style of the element in another HTML which is going to be uploaded.?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I updated the original question to better present what I mean. @Sankar

Comment: I don't think this is possible. You can't change the style of an element in another HTML file.

Comment: your problem solved or not? i just add code. just try that code

Comment: @Rupal Sadly, this has not be solved yet. I'm still trying to change the style of an element in another HTML file (the one which is being uploaded).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using input type="submit", which do page reload. So when background change to green and it reload so it is not showing your style changes. So remove type ="submit". use input type="button.and then onclick function in button. You ca use this code:-

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css" />
</head> 
<body> 
<div id="test">This is a div</div>
<form >
<p><input id="uploadInput" type="file" name="myFiles" onchange="updateSize();" multiple> selected files: <span id="fileNum">0</span>; total size: <span id="fileSize">0</span></p>
<p><input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="extract()"></p>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function extract() {
    var el = document.getElementById("test");
    el.style.background = 'green';
    el.style.color = 'red';

    }
</script>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: If I remove 'type="submit"', how do I present the changes?

Comment: using onclick in button @Philip

Comment: This only works if the id="test" is in the same file. My id="test" is in a different html file and it doesn't work. I'm getting a error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null" at "el.style.background = 'green';"

Comment: if files are included then it should not give you error. Check files is included in which you are using @Philip

Comment: I updated my original post with the full code I'm using. Still getting the same error. @Rupal

Answer (score 0):

When a form is submitted the page reloads, so...

> 1. Form is submitted,
> 2. CSS changed,
> 3. Page reloaded,
> 4. CSS is at it's default

Try using AJAX